# Can we pass the dynamic message for exported excel if there was no records in datatable

Tags: jquery, excel, asp.net-core, datatable

I have a datatable in which i have export to excel functionality. I want to show **No records found** in excel also when i have no records in datatable and i hit on export button.

Comment: Please provide an example for your code or tests to achieve the expected behavior

Comment: In this link - https://codepen.io/GiSmo/pen/pbjzXw you search 'abcd' then table have no record then click on Export Excel. You get excel in which only column name are showing. I just want to add No Data Available there in any column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [buttons.exportInfo()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportInfo()) to show `messageBottom` if no records export ：

```
messageBottom: function () {
                    if($('#example').DataTable().page.info().recordsDisplay==0){

                        return "No records found"
                    }
```

In addition , that api starts since: Buttons 1.4.0 , so just use the newer version js :

```
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js

//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js
```

[That is the updated code sample](https://codepen.io/nanyu2018/pen/MMgpjK)